# Best practice for blocking actions while waiting for ajax, per method?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In a JS component, I have several methods that respond to, for example, click events, and then fire off ajax requests. In order to prevent the same ajax request firing off several times before the first one finishes (in case of multiple clicks on the same button), I usually set a flag. So I have a variable in my component called `working` (which initially is `false`). When something is clicked I set it to `true`, and when the ajax request is done I set it back to `false`. If `working === true` I block any ajax requests.

The problem is, if `working === true`, ALL actions are blocked in the component, so no two things can be clicked at the same time. So a user can't click "save" until his "like" click right before is done.

In the code example, `respondToClickB` would be blocked until `respondToClickA` is resolved.

How can I handle this problem better?

Thank you in advance!

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            working: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        respondToClickA: function() {
            let self = this;
            if(!self.working)
            {
                self.working = true;
                axios.get('/ajax')
                    .then(function(response){
                        self.working = false;
                    });
            }
        },
        respondToClickB: function() {
            let self = this;
            if(!self.working)
            {
                self.working = true;
                axios.get('/ajax')
                    .then(function(response){
                        self.working = false;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice usage case for [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set): make `self.working` to be a `Set` object, and add/remove values to it.

`Set` is like an array, but it doesn't have order.

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            working: new Set()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        respondToClickA: function() {
            let self = this;
            if(!self.working.has('a'))
            {
                self.working.add('a')
                axios.get('/ajax')
                    .then(function(response){
                        self.working.delete('a');
                    });
            }
        },
        respondToClickB: function() {
            let self = this;
            if(!self.working.has('b'))
            {
                self.working.add('b');
                axios.get('/ajax')
                    .then(function(response){
                        self.working.delete('b');
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much.